# FOSUserBundle Event not triggered

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using the FosUserBundle and i want to hook into the controller to do custom stuffs so I use the FOSUserEvents but i cant make it work. 
Indeed my event is not triggered at all and i cant figure out why it is not.

I have required  "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev" in my composer.json and followed the exemple from the FOS github ( [FOSUserEvents hook into the controller](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md) )

Do i miss something ?

here is my configs/codes...:

```
<?php

namespace Om\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class ProfileRegisterListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router) {
        $this->router = $router;
        die('construct ProfileRegisterListener');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE => 'onRegisterSuccess',
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegisterSuccess',
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM => 'onRegisterSuccess',
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED => 'onRegisterSuccess',
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => 'onRegisterSuccess',
        );
    }

    public function onRegisterSuccess(FormEvent $event) {
        $url = $this->router->generate('/');
        die('i die onRegisterSuccess');
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

and my service.yml in my userbundle:

```
services:
om_user_registration.form.type:
    class: Om\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: om_userbundle_registration}

om_user.register_profile:
    class: Om\UserBundle\EventListener\ProfileRegisterListener
    arguments: [@router]
    tags:
        - { name: Kernel.event_subscriber}
```

In my app config.yml

```
fos_user:
db_driver: orm
firewall_name: main
user_class: Om\UserBundle\Entity\User
use_listener: true
registration:
    form:
        type: om_userbundle_registration
```

my security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            default_target_path: /profile
#            oauth:
#                resource_owners:
#                    facebook: "/login/check-facebook"
#                login_path: /login
#                failure_path: /login
#
#                oauth_user_provider:
#                    service: user_provider
        logout: true
        anonymous: true

    login:
        pattern: ^/login$
        security: false

        remember_me:
            key: "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
            path: /
            domain: ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: nothing special in logs :/
if i create a RegistrationListener.php instead of my ProfileRegisterListener.php with same code and call it as a service (same params...), the RegistrationListener works. 
But it's still weird that my ProfileRegisterListener is not fired at all, not event the construct :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return array(

        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegisterSuccess'

    );
}
```

it will be work only on REGISTRATION_SUCCESS event. If you search for FOSUserEvent. PHP you can find the purpose of each event.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old, but faced the same problem, your FOSUserBundle emails option **IS NOT** enabled.

That listener won't be triggered if you don't activate the emails in your configuration

```
# app/config/config.yml (config/packages/fos_user.yaml if you're in symfony4)
fos_user:
   # ...
   registration:
       confirmation:
           enabled: true
```

Documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/emails.html#registration-confirmation